# Process New Row Added in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, zapier

I am writing a Nodejs application that connects to a webhook of a Discord channel. The webhook takes the row of the spreadsheet and posts the data to Discord.

This was easy to implement with the Google Sheets API but the next task requires our app to monitor Google Sheets and invoke the webhook as soon as a new row is added to sheets.

I've explored the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) and found no feature that sends a notification when a new row is added. Automation tools like Zapier and Automate.io offer this sort of functionality so it should be possible.

Any suggestions on how we can trigger our Nodejs app when a new row is added to Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to run an Apps Script function when an `on change` event happens.

You may want to take a look at the [getEventObject_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/57843816?msgid=57947667) function to learn how to get the event type, modified spreadsheet range and its values from the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The trouble with Google Apps Script is that there's no way to install this trigger from the Node app and users will have to manually install the trigger.